# Javascript help function to hide each listem independently

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, html-helper

Can someone please help me with a function to hide a list element, one by one, when clicking on it? I only got it to work but for one single element, I am not sure how it would go for all of them.

Suppose I have a list of 5 elements. When i click on element 1, it dissapears. If I click on element two, it also dissapears and so on.

I would like it to do on javascript vanilla only

This is that I've tried so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<ul>
  <li id ="id1"  onclick="document.getElementById('id1').style.visibility='hidden'">Coffee</li>
  <li class ="id1"  onclick="document.getElementById('id1').style.visibility='hidden'">Coffee 2</li>
  <li class ="id1"  onclick="document.getElementById('id1').style.visibility='hidden'">Coffee 3</li>

</ul>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All your onClick get element with id1. Each one target the ID of its element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this by passing `event` parameter into a click handler function.

When you define your html like this `onclick="onListItemClick(event)"`, Javascript automatically sends the `event` object into your function.

`Event` object has many properties inside of it. But all you are concerned with is the `event.target` which is the element that you clicked on.

Then you can easily manipulate any part of that html element.

```js
function onListItemClick(event) {
  event.target.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li onclick="onListItemClick(event)">Coffee 1</li>
    <li onclick="onListItemClick(event)">Coffee 2</li>
    <li onclick="onListItemClick(event)">Coffee 3</li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use inline HTML event attributes. Best practice is delegation. Add a class to your `ul` so that you only need one `eventListener`.

```js
document.querySelector(".unordered-list").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("id1")) {
    e.target.style.opacity = 0;
  }
});
```

```html
<ul class="unordered-list">
  <li class="id1">Coffee</li>
  <li class="id1">Coffee 2</li>
  <li class="id1">Coffee 3</li>
</ul>
```